# Powershell: Unable to click "Google Search" after entering search string

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, button, click, browser-automation

I wrote the following snippet to open Internet explorer and search for a particular string. However i am unable to click the "**Google Search**" button to view the search results.

```
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application  
$site= "www.google.com"  
$IE.navigate2($site)  
$IE.visible=$true  
$search_string= "Sachin Tendulkar"  
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}  
$IE.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value= "$search_string"  
$IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "submit" -and $_.name -eq "btnK" } | ForEach-Object { $_.Click() };
```

I have even tried the following snippets to try click the "Google Search" button.

```
$submitButton = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 
Foreach($element in $submitButton )
{

    if($element.type -eq "submit" -and $element.value -eq "Google Search"){
    Write-Host $element[0].click()
    }
}
```

and the below one method too.

```
$btn = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "submit" -and $_.name -eq "btnK"} 
$btn.click();
```

I need help getting this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not open the search directly with:

```
$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$site= "www.google.com"
$search_string= "Sachin Tendulkar"
$url = "//" + $site + "/search?q=" + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($search_string)
$IE.navigate2($url)
$IE.visible=$true
```

so you get the result without clicking the submit button

Comment: That helps.
Thanks.